# Trying to block div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

```
  <script>

     var day = moment().get('day');
     var hour=moment().get('hour');

     if((day > 0 && day < 6) && (hour >= 9 && hour <= 16 )){ 
             $('#showDate').html(value); 
   }

   (.element.find('div[data-content-uuid=""]').css('display','block'); 

</script>
```

Trying to block the content in `DIV` tag for times shown below but keeps coming up with an error on the moment and `if` statement.The content to block has uuid number which is the area to be blocked. Any suggestions?

Comment: paste your html and error

Comment: "_but keeps coming up with an error on the moment and if statement_" what is the error?

Comment: Well, it looks like you're trying to access a jQuery object, but you forgot the `$`

Comment: Your question need to be reframed..

Comment: what is this? `(.element.find('...).css(...)`

Comment: working with FROG trying to block div tag to stop user accessing the drive during the day. The content div has a uuid number which represent the content. Message appear to say the following : moment not defined

Comment: element find is the link to the div tag content uuid number

Comment: The thing about error messages is, they often tell you exactly what the problem is!  "moment not defined" means you forgot to include the moment.js library.  (Also, the line Lixus pointed out has problems: `element` is undefined, and the stray dot before it is a syntax error.)

Answer (score 0):

One error I see is with your Moment.js code

```
moment().get('day');
```

is an unsupported method call.
The method call below may work and is supported by Method.js.

```
moment().get('date');
```

Comment: Okay what do I need to add?? not sure

Comment: Still did work as its both statements, for the day and hour. First statement is the block Monday to Friday and the second is from 9 till 1600 each day. But it keep saying moment  not defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
(.element.find('div[data-content-uuid=""]').css('display','block');
```

Instead of this try using

```
$('div[data-content-uuid=""]').disable();
```

Or,

```
$('div[data-content-uuid=""]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Add the uuid as shown above but problem still remain with the moment() part. Keeps saying moment not defined,

Answer (score 0):

use this code to get day:

```
var date = moment("2015-07-02");
var dow = date.day();
console.log(dow);
```

prints "4"

And use this to get hour:

```
var now = moment(); //Gets the Current Date With Time
 var time = now.hour();
```